# I am getting the error " Pricetag.jsx:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') " and the screen is blank

Tags: javascript

This is the code,

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { useState } from 'react'
// import './Cart.js'
export default function Pricetag(props) {

  const [count, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  let number = document.getElementById("number") ; 
  number.innerHTML=count; 

  return (
    <div>

      <div className="cart">
        <div id="number"></div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
      </div>

      <div className="card1">

        <div className="image">
          <img src={props.images} alt="" className='card-image' />
        </div>

        <div className="content">

          <div className="name">
            {props.name}
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="button">
          <button className='btn no1' id='cartbutton' onClick={() => setCartCount(count + 1)} >
            Add to cart  </button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

I know I could have directly used `count` but there is some display problem with that, how can I fix this particular?

This is some random text This is some random text This is some random text This is some random text This is some random text This is some random text

Comment: The element has not rendered yet - you haven't returned the JSX at the bottom yet, so the element doesn't exist yet. Wait until the element exists - or, even better, use JSX interpolation instead by figuring out and fixing whatever display problem you're referring to

Comment: Sorry, I am new to react and I am not getting your too technical answer can you show me what I need to do for now.

Comment: Did you look at the linked canonical that shows you how?